# Need to suspend and flush memcached server (or server pool) to maintain data integrity

Tags: caching, memcached

I have this problem related to maintaining and I have looked in several places for the answer but I have found no specific answer.

The situation is like this:

We have several mysql queries which generate menus for our web application. About once a day, we need to update the tables and those updates affect the menu generation. Naturally, we enclose those updates within a transaction.

So far so good. But the improve the speed and responsiveness and also reduce database load, we want to use memcached. And in all respects, memcached is perfect for this role because the updates happen only once a day.

But what we would like to do is this:

1. Our update scripts starts and its first operation is to "suspend" the memcached pool. Once this is done, memcached no longer answers queries and all queries are passed through to mysql. The important thing is that the memcached server still responds with a miss quickly so that mysql comes into action quickly. The other important thing is that during this period, memcached will refuse to set any data.
2. Flush all data in memcached pool.
3. Update script runs.
4. Restore memcached to normal operation.

So, 1. and 4. is where I am stuck.

Our technology is based around mysql and PHP. I am using the nginx memcached module to directly retrieve data from memcached. But the PHP which sets the cache could run in many different places.

Having said that, I am open to using any language or technology. This is a generic enough problem and we could discuss anything that works best.

Thanks in advance for responses.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Based on @alister_b's initial answer, there is a simpler way to solve my initial problem.

The key is to signal to the PHP code to stop setting the cache values. That can be done through memcached entry like setCache:false or through a MySQL column.

Then, a flush command will guarantee nginx cache misses.

Once the tables are updated, setCache is set to true and normal sets by php are resumed.

This will work with my Ajax calls without issues.

It is not mutually exclusive with namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method of (atomically) swapping over from one set of data in cache is with a `Namespace`. A prefix that is stored in its own key and is queried first before going on to fetch the main cached data.

It works like this:

- You have a 'namespace' under a key - it could be date/time based for example - `menuNamespace = 'menu:15050414:'` (the 2015-05-04, 2pm menu build).
- That key is a prefix for all the actual data for the menus, or other data, eg: `menu:15050414:top-menu`, `menu:15050414:l2-menu`, etc, etc
- The back end system builds a new set of cached data with new keys: `menu:15050510:top-menu`, `menu:15050510:l2-menu`
- Only when the data is in place, do you change namespace key cached entry from 'menu:15050414:' to 'menu:15050510:'
- The next time the namespace is fetched, it is used as a prefix to then fetch the new data.

There is some more in a [MemcacheD FAQ/tricks page](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingTricks#Namespacing) on Namespacing.

Comment: @alister_b, your answer is in the right direction. I think it can be made to work in our case with some modifications.

Comment: @alister_b, the namespace prefix can be in mysql because the script which updates the menus can update the prefix reliably as part of a transaction. One issue will be the generation of the Ajax URLs for the menus. Right now, I am passing a query string to control how the menu is generated. The namespace prefix can be added to this query string. But to make it work, an outdated prefix should never get data from memcached. Now the issue is this: how do I flush memcached as part of an all or nothing transaction?